# SQL Server 2008 equivalent for FETCH OFFSET with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a program with which my users can look up all the data traffic that happend the last 7 days. I use a stored procedure to get me that data - 250 records at a time (the user can page through that). The problem was, that the users get a lot of timeouts when they wanted to see that data.

Here is the stored procedure before I tried to optimize ist.

```
@MaxRecCount INT,
@PageOffset INT,
@IncludeData BIT

SELECT [Client], [Schema], [Version], [Records], [Fetched], [Receipted], [ProvidedAt], [FetchedAt], [ReceiptedAt],[PacketIds], [Record] FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@MaxRecCount) MAX(bai_ExportPendingArchive.[UserName]) AS Client,
    MAX(bai_ExportPendingArchive.Category) AS [Schema],
    MAX(bai_ExportPendingArchive.ContractVersion) AS [Version],
    COUNT(*) AS [Records],
    SUM (CASE WHEN bai_ExportPendingAckArchive.ExportPendingId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as [Fetched],
    SUM (CASE WHEN bai_ExportPendingAckArchive.Receipted IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as [Receipted],
    MAX(bai_ExportArchive.Inserted) AS [ProvidedAt],
    MAX(CASE WHEN bai_ExportPendingAckArchive.ExportPendingId IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE bai_ExportPendingAckArchive.Inserted END) AS [FetchedAt],
    MAX(CASE WHEN bai_ExportPendingAckArchive.Receipted IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE bai_ExportPendingAckArchive.Receipted END) AS [ReceiptedAt],
    bai_ExportArchive.PacketIds AS [PacketIds],
    NULL AS [Record],
    ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By MAX(bai_ExportArchive.Inserted) desc) as [RowNumber]
FROM bai_ExportArchive
INNER JOIN bai_ExportPendingArchive ON bai_ExportArchive.Id = bai_ExportPendingArchive.ExportId
LEFT OUTER JOIN bai_ExportPendingAckArchive ON bai_ExportPendingAckArchive.ExportPendingId = bai_ExportPendingArchive.Id
GROUP BY bai_ExportPendingArchive.[UserName], bai_ExportArchive.PacketIds, bai_ExportPendingArchive.Category
) AS InnerTable WHERE RowNumber > (@PageOffset * @MaxRecCount)  and RowNumber <= (@PageOffset * @MaxRecCount + @MaxRecCount)
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

@MaxRecCount, @PageOffset and @IncludeData are parameter which came from my C#-method.
This version needed about 1:35min to get me the data I wanted. To make the stored procedure faster I insered a WHERE clause to filter for the Inserted col (also I made an Index on this column) and to use OFFSET FETCH:

The stored procedure after the optimization:

```
@MaxRecCount INT, 
@PageOffset INT, 
@IncludeData BIT 

Declare @pageStart int
Declare @pageEnd int

SET @pageStart = @PageOffset * @MaxRecCount
SET @pageEnd = @pageStart + @MaxRecCount + 50

IF @IncludeData = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT [Client], [Schema], [Version], [Records], [Fetched], [Receipted], [ProvidedAt], [FetchedAt], [ReceiptedAt],[PacketIds], [Record] FROM (
            SELECT TOP(@MaxRecCount) bai_ExportPendingArchive.[UserName] AS Client,
            bai_ExportPendingArchive.Category AS [Schema],
            MAX(bai_ExportPendingArchive.ContractVersion) AS [Version],
            COUNT(*) AS [Records],
            SUM (CASE WHEN bai_ExportPendingAckArchive.ExportPendingId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as [Fetched],
            SUM (CASE WHEN bai_ExportPendingAckArchive.Receipted IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as [Receipted],
            MAX(bai_ExportArchive.Inserted) AS [ProvidedAt],
            MAX(CASE WHEN bai_ExportPendingAckArchive.ExportPendingId IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE bai_ExportPendingAckArchive.Inserted END) AS [FetchedAt],
            MAX(CASE WHEN bai_ExportPendingAckArchive.Receipted IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE bai_ExportPendingAckArchive.Receipted END) AS [ReceiptedAt],
            bai_ExportArchive.PacketIds AS [PacketIds],
            NULL AS [Record],
            ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By MAX(bai_ExportArchive.Inserted) desc) as [RowNumber]
            FROM bai_ExportArchive
            INNER JOIN bai_ExportPendingArchive ON bai_ExportArchive.Id = bai_ExportPendingArchive.ExportId
            LEFT OUTER JOIN bai_ExportPendingAckArchive ON bai_ExportPendingAckArchive.ExportPendingId = bai_ExportPendingArchive.Id
            Where bai_ExportArchive.Inserted <= (Select bai_ExportArchive.Inserted from bai_ExportArchive Order by bai_ExportArchive.Inserted DESC Offset @pageStart ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS Only)
            And bai_ExportArchive.Inserted > (Select bai_ExportArchive.Inserted from bai_ExportArchive Order by bai_ExportArchive.Inserted DESC Offset @pageEnd ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS Only)
            GROUP BY bai_ExportPendingArchive.[UserName], bai_ExportArchive.PacketIds, bai_ExportPendingArchive.Category
            ) AS InnerTable 
        ORDER BY RowNumber
```

This version gives me the data in about 2s. The only problem is, I work on Microsoft SQL Server 2014 BUT my Users use SQL Server 2008+. The Problem now is, that the OFFSET FETCH dosn't work in Server 2008. And now I'm clueless how I can optimize my stored procedure that it is fast and work on SQl Server 2008.

I'm thankful for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method to handle the pagination in `SQL Server 2005/2008`.

First use a `CTE` for your select query with a `ROW_NUMBER()` column to identify the record number/count. After that you can select a range of records from this `CTE` using your `PAGE_NUMBER` and `PAGE_COUNT`. Example is below

```
DECLARE @P_PAGE_NUM     INT =    0
        ,@P_PAGE_SIZE   INT =   20

    ;WITH CTE
    AS
    (   /*SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COL_to_SORT DESC)   AS  [ROW_NO]
                ,...
        WHERE   ....
        */ -- You can replace your select query here, but column [ROW_NO] should be there in your select list.
           --ie ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY put_column-to-sort-here DESC)   AS  [ROW_NO] 
    )

    SELECT  *
            --,(    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE) AS    [TOTAL_ROW_COUNT]
    FROM    CTE
    WHERE   (   
                ISNULL(@P_PAGE_NUM,0)   =   0   OR
                [ROW_NO]    BETWEEN (   @P_PAGE_NUM - 1) *  @P_PAGE_SIZE + 1  
                                AND     @P_PAGE_NUM      *  @P_PAGE_SIZE
            )
    ORDER BY    [ROW_NO]
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. To be honest: I have no idea how to insert you suggestion into my stored procedure.

Comment: You can replace your select query inside the CTE, but 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [put_column-to-sort-here] DESC)   AS  [ROW_NO]' column should be there to sort the records, then only we can maintain an order sequence in the records. And the Select script after the CTE will be remain same.

Comment: Ok, now I got it, I changed my stored procedure like you suggested but now it takes about 3:07min to get me the data I wanted (befor the change it was 1:35min)